# How-To Use ReorderList control from AjaxToolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

So, I've digged the internet in seach on a decent tutorial on howtta use the ReorderList control that comes in the Ajax Tookit. I've made lists that can reorder and such, the problem comes when I wanna include an edit feature. There's almost no documentation on how to do this.

How you make editable items in a reorder list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ReorderList, the only way to allow items to be editable is to postback after each reorder.

From the [ASP.Net Toolkit website](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx):

> The ReorderList can handle reorders in
>   two ways, either via a callback or via
>   a postback. For a callback, no page
>   postback happens on a reorder. This is
>   useful if the data is only to be
>   ordered. If the data items are to be
>   deleted or edited, a full postback
>   needs to occur to sync the server side
>   state with the client side state. The
>   **PostbackOnReorder** property enables
>   this.